# How to change the background of the cell of one specific day in ngb-datepicker - Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, datepicker

I am starting to work with `ngb-datepicker` and I would like to know if it is possible to change the `background-color` of one specific day, for example, the 8th of November.

**HTML**

```
<ngb-datepicker name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker [dayTemplate]="customDay" [markDisabled]="isDisabled"
    #d="ngbDatepicker"></ngb-datepicker>


<ng-template #customDay let-date let-currentMonth="currentMonth" let-selected="selected" let-disabled="disabled"
  let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day" [class.weekend]="isMarkedDay(date)" [class.focused]="focused" [class.bg-primary]="selected"
    [class.hidden]="date.month !== currentMonth" [class.text-muted]="disabled">
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  accomplishedDays: NgbDate[] = [];
  day = new Date().getDate();
  month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  year = new Date().getFullYear();
  today: NgbDate = new NgbDate(this.year, this.month, this.day); // July, 14 1789

  constructor(
    public mockdataService: MockDataService,
    private calendar: NgbCalendar
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  isDisabled = (date: NgbDate, current: { month: number }) =>
    date.month !== current.month;

  isMarkedDay = () => this.calendar.getToday() == this.today; // .getWeekday(date) >= this.today;
}
```

I have been trying it for a while but I am not able to make it work. Right now I am just trying to mark the current day but it does not work. I have checked in the console if `this.calendar.getToday()` and `this.today` prints the same and it does, but when comparing them is false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it, you can provide custom HTML template for every day in the DP, where you can easily set css class based on the day.

- check it in the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#customday), there is also [example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/datepicker/customday/stackblitz.html)

**UPDATE**

- The dates you're comparing are JS objects and you can't compare them like that (you should learn something about [JS Object comparison](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f))
- To compare them you can use built-in method on the `NgbDate` for comparing, so your code will look like this:

  `isMarkedDay = () => this.calendar.getToday().equals(this.today));`

Comment: Sorry, fixed now

Comment: Updated answer with solution